# Can I check if a String contains an emoji?

Tags: flutter

The question is simple and short.
Can I check if a String contains an emoji?

In my chat application I want all the emoji's a bit bigger than the usual font size. So I need to check if a character is an emoji. Is this even possible in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

There is a package which supports this, called [flutter_emoji](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_emoji).

Looking at the source code, the detection is quite simple:

It is using the following regex:

```dart
/// A tweak regexp to pass all Emoji Unicode 11.0
/// TODO: improve this version, since it does not match the graphical bytes.
static final RegExp REGEX_EMOJI = RegExp(r'(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])');
```

[Source Code](https://github.com/petehouston/flutter-emoji/blob/ae953acfea53bf2cb73cdec7c13058681c6fcc1f/lib/flutter_emoji.dart#L115)